# How can I pass through gameobject when using rigidbody.moveposition in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my previous post i ask how to stop at green line apple. I success stop at green line apple by change this code `transform.position = tempvec`

to

`r.MovePosition(tempVec)`

But there is this new problem, I need to pass through other apple. In old code I can pass through other apple easy but can't stop at green line apple. New code i can stop at green line apple, but can't pass through other apple, if i hit other apple it got push away.

Red apple can only move inside Green apple.

How can I pass through other apple but also stop at green line apple?

```
Camera mainCamera;
float zAxis = 0;
Vector3 clickOffset = Vector3.zero;
Rigidbody2D r;
public Transform apple;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    mainCamera = Camera.main;
    mainCamera.gameObject.AddComponent<Physics2DRaycaster>();

    zAxis = transform.position.z;
    r = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    clickOffset = transform.position - mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y, zAxis));
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    //Use Offset To Prevent Sprite from Jumping to where the finger is
    Vector3 tempVec = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(eventData.position) + clickOffset;
    tempVec.z = zAxis; 
    r.MovePosition(tempVec);
    // transform.position = tempVec;
    r.velocity = Vector3.zero ;
    r.angularVelocity = 0f;
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{

}
```

This is what my game look like. The box is where i put my apple in. The box have isTrigger checked. The box doesn't matter, just put there so you guy get better understand of my game.

[Image for better understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rauvi.png)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to be able to click and drag a red apple to the box and be able to move through the other red apples right?

Comment: @basklein yup, red apple can only move inside green apple and it pass through other apple in it way to the box.

Comment: Remove `Collider`s for the red apple

Comment: @CoderCharmander  why? if i delete collider, other code won't work

Comment: Change the colliders matrix so that the collider for red allows it to not react to green, or green not react to red..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) for your game-objects,

then go to your Project Settings from `Edit` (top right).
[image: Image of how to go to Project Settings]

Afterwards, navigate to the `Physics` tab. (Or `Physics 2D` if you are dealing with that)
[image: Image of the Physics Tab panel]

The check-boxes represents whenever a game-object with specific layer can interact with another said layer.

If it is unchecked, then game-objects with those respective layers will not collide with one another. (Provided that they have a collider)

In your case, I think you want to uncheck red apple with itself (and the other apples, except green).

Answer (score 0):

The answer @Kaynn gave pretty much covers it already. Set up [layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) for your game objects by assigning the red apples to a separate layer.

But if you want to be a bit more precise, you might want to add another layer for "HeldApple" and turn off collisions with the RedApples layer. Then you can change the layer of the apple you're holding when you click on it. That way red apples CAN still collide with each-other, but the apple you're holding can't.

Comment: Thanks, my game didn't need that part, But I will save your answer for future project.